# jQuery animate(params,options) function not working as it descriped in the manual

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

here is my code

```
this.animate({marginTop:'0px'}, {speed:'slow', queue:false});
```

the speed option is not working here, I tried different combination, still not working.

what happened here?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `duration`, not `speed`:

```
this.animate({marginTop:'0px'}, {duration:'slow', queue:false});
```

Comment: you are god damn right, but it's "speed" in the document, odd?

Comment: I can't see where it is documented as 'speed'. It is referred to as 'duration' in the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: well, I guess I need to update my local document now, thank you